# How to read from .csv and write amendments to other .csv?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a script to update several huge .csv files with this code:

```
import csv

f = open('Book1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    row[1] = row[1].split(".")[0]
```

Can't find a solution to write changes to a separate file Book1_Edited.csv.
Solutions I've found are either with pandas or rewriting an original file.

Files content, if necessary:

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Last, Volume, NumberOfTrades, BidVolume, AskVolume
2019/12/30, 14:38:01, 3233.00, 3233.00, 3230.00, 3233.00, 1, 1, 0, 1
2019/12/30, 14:38:01.1, 3233.25, 3233.00, 3230.00, 3233.25, 2, 1, 0, 2
2019/12/30, 14:43:13, 3230.00, 3230.25, 3230.00, 3230.00, 1, 1, 1, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47, 3224.50, 3224.75, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47.1, 3224.50, 3224.75, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47.2, 3224.50, 3225.50, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please post a sample of the desired result

Comment: Mike, I already got a desired result from row[1].split(".")[0] but can't save it in separate file. Each file contents 35 millions of rows with data, I'm making a small amendment removing the milliseconds from second column (.1, .2, etc) and now all I need is to save it in separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve the original data, create a second file for the save. After you modify the row from the old file, you can rejoin the row fields and write the updated row to the new file:

```
import csv

f = open('Book1.csv')   # source data
f2 = open('Book1_Edited.csv','w')  # new csv
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    row[1] = row[1].split(".")[0]
    f2.write(','.join(row) + '\n')  # join updated fields, add newline

f.close()  # close both files
f2.close()
```

Output (Book1_Edited.csv):

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Last, Volume, NumberOfTrades, BidVolume, AskVolume
2019/12/30, 14:38:01, 3233.00, 3233.00, 3230.00, 3233.00, 1, 1, 0, 1
2019/12/30, 14:38:01, 3233.25, 3233.00, 3230.00, 3233.25, 2, 1, 0, 2
2019/12/30, 14:43:13, 3230.00, 3230.25, 3230.00, 3230.00, 1, 1, 1, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47, 3224.50, 3224.75, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47, 3224.50, 3224.75, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47, 3224.50, 3225.50, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Open two different files simultaneously

```
new_fo = open('new.csv', 'w', newline='')
old_fo = open('old.csv', newline='')
rdr = csv.reader(old_fo)
wrtr = csv.writer(new_fo)
for row ...
    # modify row
    wrtr.writerow(row)

new_fo.close()
old_fo.close()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Or you can copy the file and overwrite